# SQL: best way to store yes/no values? Looking after performance in huge databases

Tags: sql, database, performance, database-design, store

I have some columns where I have to store basically yes/no values. 
For example user status for active or inactive. Newsletter suscription status for suscribed or unsuscribed.

Well I want to know (considering tables with a lot of records) if the best way is to put a tiny int with char length of 1 and set 1 for yes, and 0 for no.

Is this a correct thought? Or there are no impact in the performance of db queries when using just words like yes, no, active, inactive, suscribed, etc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that the difference between  `'yes' == 'yes'` and `'1' = '1'` is so negligible that it really doesn't matter. As long as you don't go down the `"the_value_is_true_therefore_the_user_clicked_the_agree_button"` path you should be okay. On the other hand I always been a fan of using numbers instead of strings, they give me this sense of exactitude that strings don't.

Comment: That might be true for tiny tables, but once you reach hundreds millions rows, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Semantically, I suggest you use `bit` if it's available to you. When looking at the column, any other developer can immediately determine that a boolean value is stored in it. If you don't have `bit`, try using `tinyint`. Ensuring that `1` is the only `true` value and `0` is the only `false` value will bring consistency. Otherwise, you could end up with a messy mixture of `true`/`false`, `yes`/`no`, `valid`/`invalid`, `y`/`n`, and/or `t`/`f`.

Comparing `bit` or `tinyint` values probably isn't slower than comparing strings, and even if it were slower than comparing strings, I can't imagine it having a significant effect on overall speed.

Comment: maybe a y/n would be more human-readable over a 0/1 values. wouldnt it? I mean, if its the same to store "y" over "1"

Comment: Taken on its own, I do think that `'y'`/`'n'` is more human readable than `1`/`0`. However, different developers might end up using their own "pet" letters (or even `"1"`/`"0"`!).

Additionally, it's easier to cast to a boolean `bit`/`tinyint` than it is to a letter.

Comment: " comparing bit or tinyint values probably isn't slower than comparing strings"I am a computer. I speak binary. I do not speak numbers or letters or any spoken language. I speak binary. When I compare a bit I look at a single bit. When I compare "strings" I have to look at many bits which represent you number or letter or word. Although I can do things very fast the more you ask me to do more longer it takes.

Answer (score 3):

Is there something you don't like about the 'bit' data type?

Comment: Not all databases support BIT as a data type

Comment: well i have just learned about this bit type. It may be what I need, if it really worth for the performance impact thing

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly supported means is to use `CHAR(1)` - on most databases, it takes the same amount of space as BIT (assuming BIT is available, 1 byte) but supports more values (26 if case insensitive, 52 if not) if there's any chance of supporting more values.  Unlike `BIT`, `CHAR(1)` is human readable.  Also, `BIT` isn't supported on every database.

Comment: SQL Server centric: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282462/about-choosing-data-type

Comment: Although, I find 1 and 0 to be human-readable (assuming "normal" logic where 0 is false and 1 is not false), if perhaps programmer-oriented. I would place a larger weight on consistency.

Comment: Since when is BIT not human readable? Ah, I forgot these days no one understands binary/hexadecimal representations.

Comment: Actually in SQL Server, up to 8 BIT fields can be combined into a single BYTE - that's 8 times less space than 8 CHAR(1) fields....

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, but that's only *after* you add eight BIT fields

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS supports bitmap indexes, go for BIT every time. If it doesn't, use whatever you want, there is really no difference between char(1), tinyint (byte).

Answer (score 1):

Are you just asking in general, what the most efficient way to store a yes/no flag is?
Or do you have a performance problem at hand?

If so, when do you have the performance problem (specific queries, inserts, maintenance etc)? What kind of performance gain are you looking for?
2%? 10%? 50%?

Changing datatypes will likely result in only a minor improvement unless we are talking about several hundred million rows. I will give you an example. Let's say that whatever change you did, you shaved of 3 bytes per row. Let's say the table contains 100,000,000 rows. That would be a saving of ~285 mb. Assuming the disk subsystem can provide you 100mb/s you have saved a whopping 3 seconds for a full table scan. Something tells me that the users would think 2 hours and 3 seconds vs 2 hours is same same :)

Answer (score 0):

My intuition would have said performance would have been better with tinyints, but [this post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/) doesn't really bare that thought out. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628551/is-there-an-advantage-on-setting-tinyint-fields-when-i-know-that-the-value-will-n) post also offers some other interesting opinions.

I do think that performing analysis with data stored as numbers is typically easier than character data. What other programs are you going to have to interface with and use? For example, several of my analysis tools do not read character data at all, so we have to recode any data we receive in the format of "yes", "no", etc.

Comment: Hmm, reminds me of [boolean truths](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Boolean-Truths.aspx)